# macOS Monterey 12.1 - Disable MagicMouse horizontal scrolling

Tags: mouse, macos, monterey

How can I disable the horizontal scrolling feature of the MagicMouse? I have tried with some terminal commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseHorizontalScroll -bool false
```

but no luck. Some suggest a small app call MagicPref but that's unsupported and old software.

Other than getting read of the not-so-magic mouse, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

I found a program called [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) that is working for me, but I really want to find a software-free way to do this, like the terminal commands that used to work. So, BetterTouchTool (free for 45 days) might do the trick for you, or you may want a different answer. For me, before I'd buy software to make this mouse behave, I'd use a different mouse.

Comment: I have ditched the not so MagicMouse for a Logitech Bluetooth keyboard and mouse that not only works better but its also cheaper.